# Discontinuity of potential due to point charge at dielectric boundary

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage, dielectric

Suppose we have point charge $q$ enclosed in a uniform spherical dielectric medium of dielectric constant $\epsilon$ with radius $R$. The electric field due to that would be:
$$
\vec{E}(r) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} &,& 0<r<R \\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} &,& r>R
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, the electrostatic potential is given by:
$$
\phi(r) = \int_{r}^\infty\vec{E}(r').\vec{dr'}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{1}{r} &,& 0<r<R \\
\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r} &,& r>R
\end{cases}
$$
Using the above expression, we see that electric **potential** is discontinuous at $r = R$, which means I am doing something wrong here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: What about the integration constant?

Comment: thank u! i wrote this wrong!